# How to position two elements side by side using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to position a paragraph to the right of an `<iframe>` of a Google map.

I do not know how to show my code, so here is a screenshot of what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just use the float style. Put your google map iframe in a div class, and the paragraph in another div class, then apply the following CSS styles to those div classes(don't forget to clear the blocks after float effect, to not make the blocks trouble below them):

**css**

```
.google_map{
    width:55%;
    margin-right:2%;
    float: left;
}
.google_map iframe{
   width:100%;
}
.paragraph {
    width:42%;
    float: left;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="google_map">
      <iframe></iframe>
</div>
<div class="paragraph">
      <p></p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 51):

You have two options, either `float:left` or `display:inline-block`.

Both methods have their caveats. It seems that `display:inline-block` is more common nowadays, as it avoids some of the issues of floating.

Read this article http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/ or this one http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/ for a more in detail discussion.

Comment: "display: inline-block" is the right one. "float: left" could lead to some troubles when positioning items..

Answer (score 26):

You can simply use a div to make a container and `display: flex;` to make the content appear side-by-side like this:

```css
.splitscreen {
  display: flex;
}

.splitscreen .left,
.splitscreen .right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="splitscreen">
  <div class="left">
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

None of these solutions seem to work if you increase the amount of text so it is larger than the width of the parent container, the element to the right still gets moved below the one to the left instead of remaining next to it.  To fix this, you can apply this style to the left element:

```
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
```

And apply this style to the right element:

```
margin-left: 50px;
```

Just make sure that the margin-left for the right element is greater than or equal to the width of the left element.  No floating or other attributes are necessary.  I would suggest wrapping these elements in a div with the style:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Applying this style may not be necessary depending on surrounding elements

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2b0bqqse/

You can see the text to the right is taller than the element to the left outlined in black.  If you remove the absolute positioning and margin and instead use float as others have suggested, the text to the right will drop down below the element to the left

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qrx78u20/

Comment: Text will move below only if total width (element floating on left side + right side + paddings + margins + borders) cross 100% of screen width.

Answer (score 5):

For your `iframe` give an outer `div` with `style` `display:inline-block`, And for your paragraph `div` also  give `display:inline-block`

**HTML**

```
<div class="side">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
<div class="side">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.side {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use either float or inline elements:

Example [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ugoMISi/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>float example</div>
  <div><div style="float:left">Floating left content</div><div>Some content</div></div>
  <div>inline block example</div>
  <div><div style="display:inline-block">Some content</div><div style="display:inline-block">Next content</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```css
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97wDh/37/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float:left` to align div in one line.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJp93/)

Answer (score 1):

You can `float` the elements (the map wrapper, and the paragraph),
or use `inline-block` on both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `iframe` inside the `<p>` and make the `iframe` CSS

```
float:left;
```

display:inline-block;

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the iframe in a class, float that left.

The paragraph with then be forced up and to the right as long as there is room for it.
Then set your paragraph to display:inline-block, and add some left margin to tidy it up.

```
<div class="left">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" /> <!--placeholder for iframe-->
</div>
<p>Lorem Paragraph Text</p>


.left { float: left; }
p { display: inline-block; margin-left: 30px;  }
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4DACH/

Answer (score 0):

give your boxes the class `foo` (or whatever) and add the css

```
.foo{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: `display:inline-block` has no effect if you're already floating.