# How can I make two tables side to side?

Tags: css

How can I make two tables side to side.
The problem may come that sometimes a table can be bigger that the other 
table next to it, so this could cause a problem and the tables below may not align, I would like to work around.
In the demo I made i have four tables so I would like it to have two tables side by side and if the second table has a longer length then the third and fourth table will align.
Is this possible.

I made a fiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/W382S/

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<table>
<tr >
<caption>test</caption>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Employee First Name</th>
<th>Employee Last Name</th>
<th>Stars<br/></th>
</tr>

<cfoutput query="shiningStar">
<tr >
<td>##</td>
<td>##</td>
<td>##</td>
<td>##</td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
</div>



#page-wrap {
    margin: 50px;
}
p {
    margin: 20px 0; 
}

    table { 
        width: 40%; 
        border-collapse: collapse; 
    }

    tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
        background: #eee; 
    }
    th { 
        background: #333; 
        color: white; 
        font-weight: bold; 
    }
    td, th { 
        padding: 3px; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        text-align: center; 
    }

caption {
  background: #dbb768;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Comment: `#page-wrap{margin:10px;float:left;}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to position two elements side by side using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089933/how-to-position-two-elements-side-by-side-using-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can not have duplicate id's.  So change all #page-wrap to classes, and make the divs display:inline-block or float them left. So if the tables width do accommodate two tables per row, it will display two tables per row.

Is this something you are looking for? : http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/eHmhn

Comment: Not sure what you were trying to show me with the link?

Comment: I dont know how that happened but just noticed that my pen was empty. Try this one: http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/BDrIa

Comment: its good now, I just notice that it works different in IE AND CHROME , havent try firefox yet.

Comment: I made more changes to the same pen, could you please have a look and tell me if this fixed the issues with the browser.