# Can't get div objects to sit side by side

Tags: html, css

My html code:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="main content"></div>
    <div id="summary"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

My css code:

```
#content {
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

#main content {
    width:75%;
    float:left;
}

#summary {
    width:25%;
    float:right;
}
```

Frankly, I have no idea why my "summary" div is still on the bottom of my "main content". I want it to be to the right of it, taking up only 75% of the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position two elements side by side using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089933/how-to-position-two-elements-side-by-side-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Changed `<div class="main content` to `<div class="maincontent">`

Don't use a space in your class names kids. Gets you in trouble

Answer (score 0):

You have named the ID wrongly "main content". You can not have space in id. 
Change it to main_content and the CSS accordingly. It should make it work