# I'm not able to place this image beside text in HTML & CSS, how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css

How can I get the image placed beside the text?

```css
.column section {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #16BAC5;
  padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Alfa Slab One";
}

.column aside img {
  align: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="column">
        <section>
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum Text</h3>
        </section>
        <aside>
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dapino/people/512/black-man-icon.png" alt="man" id="man" style="width:200px; height= 200px;">
        </aside>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: try: `float: right` on the img

Comment: The image goes to the right under the text block, not beside it when I do this.

Comment: Your image is in different sections. You need to study HTML better. It's not in the normal flow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CSS ≪ float ≫ proprity :

```
 float: left;
```

or

```
 float: right;
```

Answer (score 0):

One classic way to accomplish this would be to add `float: left` to your text and `float: right` to your image: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdBaxp

```css
.column section {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #16BAC5;
  padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Alfa Slab One";
  float: left;
}

.column aside img {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <section>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum Text</h3>
    </section>
    <aside>
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dapino/people/512/black-
    man-icon.png" alt="man" id="man" style="width:200px; height= 200px;">
    </aside>
    </div>
```

For other potential solutions, check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089933/how-to-position-two-elements-side-by-side-using-css).

Answer (score 0):

Apply right to aside, not to image inside this. Make aside narrower, so that there is room for text before this and float this to right:

```css
// Here is my CSS code:

.column section {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #16BAC5;
  padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Alfa Slab One";
}

.column aside {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="column">
      <section>
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum Text</h3>
      </section>
      <aside>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dapino/people/512/black-man-icon.png" alt="man" id="man" style="width:200px; height= 200px;">
      </aside>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<aside>` is not applying any particular placement/layout settings by default - it's up to you to define CSS settings for it (for example if you want to style it as a sidebar).

`<aside>` is an HTML5 element (not linked to any CSS property) and is something that is considered semantically as a seperate section with additional information.

That said, if you just want to place an image on the right side inside your text, don't use `aside`, but apply `float: right` to the image and put it directly into the text flow. It will the be on the right side and the text will float around it.

```css
.x {
width: 400px;
background: #eee;
}
.x img {
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
<h3>Some header</h3>
<img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/fa0">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. ras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. </p>

<p>Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat.</p>
</div>
```