# Create two table side by side using HTML

Tags: html

I know it has been already asked about how to create two tables in HTML side by side.
But those answers doesn't solve my problem.

I am already aware we can use:
display: inline-block or
float: left

But in my case number of cell in table is too much that second table moves below first table.
My fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vyzmgews/1/

```html
<table border=1 style="display: inline-block">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell1 content</td>
        <td>Cell2 content</td>
        <td>Cell3 content</td>
        <td>Cell4 content</td>
        <td>Cell5 content</td>
        <td>Cell6 content</td>
        <td>Cell7 content</td>
        <td>Cell8 content</td>
        <td>Cell9 content</td>
        <td>Cell8 content</td>
        <td>Cell9 content</td>
        <td>Cell8 content</td>
        <td>Cell9 content</td>
        <td>Cell8 content</td>
        <td>Cell9 content</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border=1 style="display: inline-block">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can i keep both the table side by side with the scroll bar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position two elements side by side using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089933/how-to-position-two-elements-side-by-side-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrapp both tables in a `div` and define for it `display: flex`.

**Working example:**

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell1 content</td>
      <td>Cell2 content</td>
      <td>Cell3 content</td>
      <td>Cell4 content</td>
      <td>Cell5 content</td>
      <td>Cell6 content</td>
      <td>Cell7 content</td>
      <td>Cell8 content</td>
      <td>Cell9 content</td>
      <td>Cell8 content</td>
      <td>Cell9 content</td>
      <td>Cell8 content</td>
      <td>Cell9 content</td>
      <td>Cell8 content</td>
      <td>Cell9 content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if display: flex; can be read properly in IE11. As this is working fine in chrome but not in IE11. Is there anyother way i can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply wrap them in another (borderless) table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border=1 class="inlineTable">
        <tr>
          <td>Cell1 content</td>
          <td>Cell2 content</td>
          <td>Cell3 content</td>
          <td>Cell4 content</td>
          <td>Cell5 content</td>
          <td>Cell6 content</td>
          <td>Cell7 content</td>
          <td>Cell8 content</td>
          <td>Cell9 content</td>
          <td>Cell8 content</td>
          <td>Cell9 content</td>
          <td>Cell8 content</td>
          <td>Cell9 content</td>
          <td>Cell8 content</td>
          <td>Cell9 content</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table border=1 class="inlineTable">
        <tr>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
          <td>Cell content</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code? Im not sure is this what you are expect.

```
<div class="row">
   <table border=1 class="inlineTable">
       <tr>
            <th>Cell1 topic</th>
            <th>Cell1 topic</th>
            <th>Cell1 topic</th>      
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell1 content</td>
            <td>Cell1 content</td>
            <td>Cell1 content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border=1 class="inlineTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

or you can add 2 column grid for that.