# how to split a too-long table into two tables in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

We have this table that's too many rows, and my boss wants me to split it so that it's two tables, side by side. The table is just the name of a service on the left, with a picture indicating the status on the right. I only just started using React today, so I'm a little unfamiliar (most of this code isn't mine), and I was hoping someone could help me figure out

1. how to divide the table, and
2. how to make the other table full of data float to the right of this one. It doesn't need to be detailed or anything, just maybe what to look for in React/CSS documentation.

This is the code to create the table (sorry it copy-pasted kind of messy). The CSS is kind of all over the place from previous employees working, but it's mostly just a border change here, a font size there, that kind of thing. I can post it if you need it.

```
  <table id="process-table" className='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
  <thead>
    <tr style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white' }}>
      <th>Process Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {ProcessInfo.map(ProcessInfo =>
        <tr key={ProcessInfo.application}>
            <td><h1>{McProcessInfo.application}</h1></td>
            {/*This td element's dot color is dynamically set based on the errorLevel property of the ProcessInfo object:*/}
            {/*react component to write error level if statement */}
            <>
                {(() => {
                    if (ProcessInfo.errorLevel == 0) { sourceStr = greenDot; }
                    else if (ProcessInfo.errorLevel <= 3) { sourceStr = yellowDot; }
                    else if (ProcessInfo.errorLevel <= 5) { sourceStr = redDot; }
                    else { sourceStr = blackDot; }
                    rowCount++;
                }
                )()}
            </>
            <td className='dot-box'>
                <div id = 'table-cell'>
                    <img src={sourceStr} height="15" width="15" />
                </div>
            </td>
      </tr>
    )}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I haven't tried anything yet, I didn't even know how to look it up, which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: You should immediately change your code so that you don't have multiple elements with the same ID (`<div id = 'table-cell'>`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to position two elements side by side using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089933/how-to-position-two-elements-side-by-side-using-css)

Comment: Splitting the table is simply rendering two tables, one right after the other, with half the data it each. `ProcessInfo.filter((item, i) => i < ProcessInfo.length / 2).map` in one, `ProcessInfo.filter((item, i) => i >= ProcessInfo.length / 2).map` in the other.

Comment: @HereticMonkey this looks really promising, but where do you put those filter statements? I'm a bit new to this style of coding, sorry if that's a stupid question

Comment: Where you have `ProcessInfo.map` for one table, you make two tables with those statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to control the layout, display the container of tables as `flex`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Two Tables in the Same Row</title>
<style>
  .table-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; //or center
  }
  .table {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  .table th, .table td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px 12px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="table-container">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Header A</th>
        <th>Header B</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row A, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row A, Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row B, Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row B, Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So it will create 2 tables in 1 row

Comment: tried this, and I think it works for regular HTML tables, but because of the way we're importing data with an array and creating a table dynamically, it just makes 1 table with the header and 1 table with the rest of the body.